# How to prevent user from injecting field into form backing bean?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

An user upload his comment via this form.

**Thymeleaf**

```
<form th:action="@{/comment}" th:id="form" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" th:name="productId.id" th:value="${product.id}">
  <textarea th:field="${comment.message}" class="comment"
                                  placeholder="Write comment here"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="comment">
</form>
```

Actual **HTML**

```
<form action="/comment" id="form" method="post" class="">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="f6b3f296-3284-4d2d-a2b2-0a9975f5e071">
  <input type="hidden" name="productId.id" value="38">
  <textarea class="comment" placeholder="Write comment here" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="comment">
</form>
```

However if user overwrites the actual HTML like this, **the product's name will be changed to "ABCD"**

```
<form action="/comment" id="form" method="post" class=""><input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="f6b3f296-3284-4d2d-a2b2-0a9975f5e071">
  <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="38">
  <input type="hidden" name="productId.name" value="ABCD">
  <textarea class="comment" placeholder="Write comment here" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="comment">
</form>
```

I think what happened here is Spring queried the `productId` and it became `managed Entity`, and when the user set the name to be "ABCD", it would be saved.

**Here is my solution**:

Basically just use `@Validated` with a bunch of groups and put constraint with appropriate groups (`UploadCommentValidation` in this case) on every single field, which works but seems really messy especially when it gets big.

**Example with upload comment above**:

- Comment Entity: `productId` and `message` must be `@Not Null`, `productId` must be `@Valid`,other fields must be `@Null`
- Product Entity: `Id` must be `@NotNull`, other fields must be `@Null`

**Comment entity**

```
public class Comment implements Comparable<Comment> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Null(groups = {UploadCommentValidation.class})
    @NotNull(groups = {DeleteCommentValidation.class, UpdateCommentValidation.class})
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    @Valid
    @NotNull(groups = {UploadCommentValidation.class})
    @Null(groups = {DeleteCommentValidation.class, UpdateCommentValidation.class})
    private Product productId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    @Null(groups = {UploadCommentValidation.class, DeleteCommentValidation.class, UpdateCommentValidation.class})
    private User userId;

    @Column(name = "message")
    @NotBlank(message = "please write a comment", groups = {UploadCommentValidation.class, UpdateCommentValidation.class})
    @Null(groups = {DeleteCommentValidation.class})
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "created_at", insertable = false, columnDefinition = "timestamp with time zone not null")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Null(groups = {UploadCommentValidation.class, DeleteCommentValidation.class, UpdateCommentValidation.class})
    private Calendar createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at", columnDefinition = "timestamp with time zone not null")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Null(groups = {UploadCommentValidation.class, DeleteCommentValidation.class, UpdateCommentValidation.class})
    private Calendar updatedAt;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Comment o) {
        return this.getId().compareTo(o.getId());
    }
}
```

**Product entity**

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull(message = "product id null", groups = {AddOrderValidation.class, UploadCommentValidation.class})
    @Null(message = "bad request", groups = {ProductRegisterValidation.class})
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank(message = "please fill in product name", groups = {ProductRegisterValidation.class})
    @Length(max = 255, message = "too long", groups = {ProductRegisterValidation.class})
    @Null(groups = {AddOrderValidation.class, UploadCommentValidation.class})
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    @Positive(message = "the price must be non-negative", groups = {ProductRegisterValidation.class})
    @NotNull(message = "please fill in price", groups = {ProductRegisterValidation.class})
    @Null(groups = {AddOrderValidation.class, UploadCommentValidation.class})
    private Integer price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "please select category name", groups = {ProductRegisterValidation.class})
    @Null(groups = {AddOrderValidation.class, UploadCommentValidation.class})
    private Category categoryId;

    @NotBlank(message = "please fill in description", groups = {ProductRegisterValidation.class})
    @Length(max = 10000, message = "too long", groups = {ProductRegisterValidation.class})
    @Null(groups = {AddOrderValidation.class, UploadCommentValidation.class})
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Null(groups = {ProductRegisterValidation.class, AddOrderValidation.class, UploadCommentValidation.class})
    private List<ProductImage> productImages;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Null(groups = {ProductRegisterValidation.class, AddOrderValidation.class, UploadCommentValidation.class})
    private Thumbnail thumbnail;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    @Null(groups = {ProductRegisterValidation.class, AddOrderValidation.class, UploadCommentValidation.class})
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Null(groups = {ProductRegisterValidation.class, AddOrderValidation.class, UploadCommentValidation.class})
    private List<Order> orders;
}
```

Any ideas how to do it the right way? This seems super messy!

**UPDATE 1**: This is my rest controller

```
@PostMapping("/comment")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> commentResponseEntity(@Validated({UploadCommentValidation.class}) Comment comment, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            result.getAllErrors().forEach(System.out::println);
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }
        User user = getUser();
        comment.setUserId(user);
        commentRepository.saveAndFlush(comment);
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("comment", comment.getMessage());
        response.put("user", user.getName());
        response.put("commentId", comment.getId().toString());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
    }
```

Comment: It is not actually related to hibernate. Your issue is in your `POST` rest endpoint. If you don't want certain fields to be modified, you need to guard your rest endpoint accordingly. Can you add your Rest endpoint?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai i just update the question. Can you help me out?

Comment: Don't expose your entities, use dedicated form objects or DTO's those should only contain the information that you need to fullfil your business need. Copy the fields to the actual product/comment whatever your domain object is and persist. No risk of overwriting existing data.

Comment: @M.Deinum you mean create a class like `CommentUploadForm` which has nothing to do with any entities but only contains user's input?

Comment: That is what i meant yes. Your entities should, ideally, not leak to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by registering an `@InitBinder` method

You can do this at the individual controller level or by registering a `@ControllerAdvice` to be applied to all, or a subset of all, controllers.

```
@InitBinder()
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields(new String[] { "id", "version" });
}
```